# Error in AWS Glue job "LAUNCH ERROR | File --class does not existPlease refer logs for details."

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-workflow

I'm getting an error after running a Glue job from workflow.
The error states
**"LAUNCH ERROR | File --class does not existPlease refer logs for details."**
We have tried passing job parameter as well "--class GlueApp" though our job is python.
I think some how it's not considering the parameter. This should be a default parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message is bit misleading

I recently encountered a very similar error `LAUNCH ERROR | File --enable-job-insights does not existPlease refer logs for details.`, and it had nothing to do with the configuration of `--enable-job-insights` parameter.

The problem was our terraform script was setting the `--extra-py-files` value as an empty string if there are no extra py files for the job, changing it to set `null` value instead of an empty string solved this issue for me.

So to solve this make sure you are not setting any configuration value as an empty string or unexpected value.

I also reported this issue to AWS.

Comment: This answer is pure gold. It also solves problem if you have error message "LAUNCH ERROR | File --auto-scaling-min-workers-default does not existPlease refer logs for details."